# how to increment a number by another number with max and min value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, math

I have a very small problem, but unfortunately I could not solve it, so I hope someone can help me, so I'm trying to make a scroll animation and move some element using the css matrix attribute and the matrix have this parameters
`scaleX(), skewY(), skewX(), scaleY(), translateX(), translateY()`
so i use the scale and translateX and translateY to animate and move the element,
i use the scrollY position value to know when to start the animation and use the y position value to move the element like this

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, ${yPositionValue}, -35)
```

so when the user scroll the y value increment or decrement, now my first way to solve the problem is to hardcode the values like if the yScroll value is 1000 then i want the animation to start so i make a event listener to the scroll if the value is 1000 then subtract the 1000 from the scroll Y position then i will start from 0 then i will move my element until i want them to stop, as you can see it's a stupid way there are many if, so what i think is a good way is to use the scroll y position value and generate a new number according to the y value that start from min and max value, so i try the next

so my first problem is when is start the animation and i use the Observer API and use the thresholds values so if the 50% of the element is visible then i start the animation, know for the scroll position i use the min and max values to give my a number between two values just like this

```
const PositionValue = (Math.min(250, Math.max(0, yOffset)));
```

so the yOffset is the y scroll position this code is work great but the problem that i it dont work very well with small number like if i want a number between 0.55 and 1.0 it doesn't give what i want so instead of this

```
const PositionValue = (Math.min(1, Math.max(0.55, yOffset)));
```

i did this

```
const PositionValue = (Math.min(100, Math.max(55, yOffset))) / 100;
```

so i can get number between 0.55, 1.0, i want to flip this number so instead of start from 0.55 to 1.0 i want to start from 1.0 to 0.55, i tried to make a variable and assigned a 1 and if the PositionValue is bigger then 0.55 it will decrement by 0.01, all i want is a way to generate a number according to the y value, i know that there is a libraries like GSAP but i like to make it by my self i use react this is my full code

```
    // observer testing
    const [isIntersectionRatioComplete, setisIntersectionRatioComplete] = useState(false);
    const observerElement = useRef(null);

    const leftSwitchRef = useRef(null);
    const centerSwitchRef = useRef(null);
    const rightSwitchRef = useRef(null);

    const observerOptions = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: []
    }
    let cenetrSwitchScalingValue = 1;
    const HandelScrollTriggerAnimation = () => {
        const yOffset =  window.pageYOffset - 1230;
        if (yOffset > 0) {
            const SwitchPositionValue = (Math.min(250, Math.max(0, yOffset)));
            // const cenetrSwitchScalingValue = (Math.min(100, Math.max(56, yOffset))) / 100; // 0.56, 1
            if (cenetrSwitchScalingValue >= 0.56) {
                cenetrSwitchScalingValue = cenetrSwitchScalingValue - 0.01;
            }
            if (leftSwitchRef.current && centerSwitchRef.current && rightSwitchRef.current) {
                leftSwitchRef.current.style.transform = `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, ${-SwitchPositionValue}, -35)`;
                centerSwitchRef.current.style.transform = `matrix(${cenetrSwitchScalingValue}, 0, 0, ${cenetrSwitchScalingValue}, 70, ${-SwitchPositionValue})`;
                rightSwitchRef.current.style.transform = `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, ${SwitchPositionValue}, -35)`;
            } return
        } return
    }

    const observerCallbackFunction = (entries) => {
        const [ entry ] = entries;
        if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.1) { //0.5
            // alert("done")
            setisIntersectionRatioComplete(true)
        } else {
            setisIntersectionRatioComplete(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        for(let i = 0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.1) {
            observerOptions.threshold.push(i);
        }
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallbackFunction, observerOptions);
        if (observerElement.current) observer.observe(observerElement.current);

        if (isIntersectionRatioComplete) {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', HandelScrollTriggerAnimation, { passive: true });
        }

        return () => {
            if (observerElement.current) {
                observer.unobserve(observerElement.current);
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', HandelScrollTriggerAnimation);
            }
        }
    }, [isIntersectionRatioComplete])
```

**for more explanation** if you see apple website [here](https://www.apple.com/homepod-mini/) you can see there animation how smooth it is what is the right approach to make like this animation
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `const PositionValue = (Math.max(55, Math.min(100, 100-yOffset))) / 100;`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It really helped me a lot, Do you think there is a better way than this one?

Comment: I think it's quite the optimal way to do the math.